# ¿Como puedo actualizar tabla sin recargar la pagina al insertar? En codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Estoy intentando acualizar la tabla al insertar en un formulario que se encuentra arriba de la tabla. intente con un table.reload pero no consigo el objetivo. Alguien me podria ayudar por favor. estoy usanso ajax al enviar formulario. Utilizo codeigniter.

Este es mi formulario

```
  <form action="" id="recep"  method="post">
                        <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <div class="form-line">
                                <label for="">CLAVE:</label>
                                <input  list="medicamento_id" name="medicamento_id" id="medicamento_id" type="text" class="form-control" style="text-transform:uppercase;" required>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <div class="form-line">
                                <label for="">DESCRIPCIÓN:</label>
                                <input name="medicamento_desc" id="medicamento_desc" type="text" class="form-control"   style="text-transform:uppercase;" readonly>
                                <input name="stock" id="stock" type="hidden" class="form-control"   style="text-transform:uppercase;" >                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="form-line">
                            <label for="">FECHA RECEPCIÓN</label>
                            <input required name="fecha_de_entrada" id="fecha_de_entrada" type="date" class="form-control"   style="text-transform:uppercase;" required>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="form-line">
                            <label for="">ORDEN COMPRA</label>
                            <input required name="orden_compra" id="orden_compra" type="text" class="form-control"  style="text-transform:uppercase;">
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center">
                          <button type="submit" id="butsave" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light">Guardar</button>

                        </div>
                      </form>
```

Esta es mi tabla para actualizar, la tabla esta debajo del formulario

```
<div class="sparkline13-graph">
                      <div class="asset-inner" >
                        <br><br><br><br><br>
                        <table id="table_id" class="table table-striped table-bordered .newT" style="width:100%">
                          <thead>
                            <tr>
                            <th class="text-center">CLAVE</th>
                            <th class="text-center">DESCRIPCIÓN</th>
                            <th class="text-center">FECHA RECEPCIÓN</th>
                            <th class="text-center">CANTIDAD</th>
                            <th class="text-center">CADUCIDAD</th>
                            <th class="text-center">LOTE</th>
                            <th class="text-center">ORDEN DE COMRA</th>
                            </tr>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody>
                            <?php //print_r($pacientes); die();?>
                            <?php foreach($recepciones as $recepcion): ?>
                              <tr>
                                <td class="text-center"><?= $recepcion->medicamento_id ?></td>
                                <td class="text-justify"><?= $recepcion->medicamento_desc ?></td>
                                <td class="text-justify"><?= $recepcion->fecha_de_entrada ?></td>
                                <td  name="r" id="r" class="text-justify"><?= $recepcion->entrante ?></td>
                                <td class="text-justify"><?= $recepcion->fecha_caducidad ?> </td>
                                <td class="text-justify"><?= $recepcion->lote ?></td>
                                <td class="text-justify"><?= $recepcion->orden_compra ?></td>

                                <?php if($this->session->userdata('modificar')== 1): ?>

                                <?php endif; ?>
                          </tr>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                      </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

Este es mi codigo al enviar fomulario. Estoy utlizando ajax. Mi objetivo es hacer que se al mandar alerta se logre actualizar la tabla sin recargar la pagina.

```
<script>
    $('#butsave').on('click', function() {
      var medicamento_id = $('#medicamento_id').val();
      var medicamento_desc = $('#medicamento_desc').val();
      var stock = $('#stock').val();
      var fecha_de_entrada = $('#fecha_de_entrada').val();
      var entrante = $('#entrante').val();
      var fecha_caducidad = $('#fecha_caducidad').val();
      var lote = $('#lote').val();
      var orden_compra = $('#orden_compra').val();

      if(medicamento_id!="",orden_compra!=""){
        $("#butsave").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $.ajax({
          url: "<?= base_url() ?>index.php/Inventario/altaRecepcion",
          type: "POST",
          data: {
            type: 1,
            medicamento_id: medicamento_id,
            medicamento_desc: medicamento_desc,
            stock: stock,
            fecha_de_entrada: fecha_de_entrada,
            entrante: entrante,
            fecha_caducidad: fecha_caducidad,

            lote: lote,
            orden_compra: orden_compra
          },
          cache: false,
          success: function(dataResult){
            var dataResult = JSON.parse(dataResult);
            if(dataResult.statusCode==200){
              $("#butsave").removeAttr("disabled");
              $("#success").show();
              swal({
                title: "INFORMACIÓN GUARDADA CORRECTAMENTE",
                type: "success",
                allowEscapeKey: false,
                showCancelButton: false,
                confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
                confirmButtonText: "¡LISTO!",
                closeOnConfirm: true,},
                function(isConfirm){
                  if (isConfirm) {
                    swal.close();
                    $('#table_id').DataTable().ajax.reload();
                  } else {
                $('#table_id').DataTable().ajax.reload();
                  }
                });
          }
            else if(dataResult.statusCode==201){
               alert("Error  !");
            }

          }
        });
      }
      else{

      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Mi solución seria crear un nuevo div que encierre a la tabla y luego actualizar el div. Por ejemplo:

```
<div id="table_refresh">
  <table id="table_id">
      <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>NOMBRE</th>
        <th>APELLIDO</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>MAIKEL</td>
        <td>SANDOVAL</td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Y para actualizar, una vez la petición haya sido exitosa agrego en jquery:

```
$("#table_refresh").load(" #table_refresh");
```

Puedes actualizar directamente la tabla sin crear el div pero yo recomiendo con div, prueba y veras porqué!

Answer (score 0):

En javascript, puedes hacer con lo siguiente:

```
setInterval(PonesElNombreDeLaFuncion, 0);
```

En donde el `0` es el tiempo a establecer para su actuación cada vez que lo requieras y se va actualizando.

---

Recuerda que debes incluirlo cuando sepas que terminaste todo bien o tendrás conflicto con tu código.